# Getting top cloners in my Database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wondered if anyone could at least help me find where to start with this. I understand its a large question but I have looked for a while and I can't find anything related to how to do with this two columns.

I have a table called 'users', I want to select the top 20 with the most cloned accounts. When I say cloned accounts, I mean that I want to show a list of user's usernames who have the most accounts with the same IP or Machine ID.

The IP column is called ip_last and the machine column is called machine_id.

How would I go about getting the top 20 with the most cloned accounts? All I want to display is the username, how many accounts cloned by IP, and how many accounts cloned by Machine.

Id accept knowing how to do this in MySQL, but if someone could help me get it working with Laravel then that would also help a lot.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How can I provide a MCVE when I don't know how to do the query?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
$result = DB::table('users')
             ->select('ip_last', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('ip_last')
             ->take(20);
```

The same is for `machine_id`, and for both you can try `->groupBy('ip_last','machine_id')`.

Comment: This is just getting a list of unique IP addresses? I don't see how this is even remotely close to what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested, but this should to the trick:

```
DB::table("users")
->select("username", DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS `cloned`"))
->whereIn("ip_last", function ($query) {
    $query->select("ip_last")
        ->from("users")
        ->groupBy("ip_last")
        ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) > 1");
})
->orWhereIn("machine_id", function ($query) {
    $query->select("machine_id")
        ->from("users")
        ->groupBy("machine_id")
        ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) > 1");
})
->orderBy("cloned", "DESC")
->limit(20);
```

Comment: When using this I receive an error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I also added ->get() on the end as you didn't, its now giving me this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `username`, COUNT(*) AS `cloned` from `users` where `ip_last` in (select `ip_last` from `users` group by `ip_last` having COUNT(*) > 1) or `machine_id` in (select `machine_id` from `users` group by `machine_id` having COUNT(*) > 1) order by `cloned` desc limit 20)