# Getting top duplicated account by IP & Machine's usernames?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to know why this code isn't working, but first I'll explain what I want to try and do. I have to create a top 10 list of usernames in the table "users" that have the most cloned accounts (IP cloned + Machine cloned) and then show how many clones they have via IP, and how many clones they have via machine.

When I say clone, I mean the same column `ip_last` and column `machine_id` so that it was either created by the same ip, or the same machine.

I'm writing this in Laravel and I have tried the below code first:

```
$cloneList = DB::table("users")
        ->select("username", DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS `cloned`"))
        ->whereIn("ip_last", function ($query) {
            $query->select("ip_last")
                ->from("users")
                ->groupBy("ip_last")
                ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) > 1");
        })
        ->orWhereIn("machine_id", function ($query) {
            $query->select("machine_id")
                ->from("users")
                ->groupBy("machine_id")
                ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) > 1");
        })
        ->orderBy("cloned", "DESC")
        ->limit(20)->get();
```

Errors I am having:

```
(1/2) PDOException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

and

```
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `username`, COUNT(*) AS `cloned` from `users` where `ip_last` in (select `ip_last` from `users` group by `ip_last` having COUNT(*) > 1) or `machine_id` in (select `machine_id` from `users` group by `machine_id` having COUNT(*) > 1) order by `cloned` desc limit 20)
```

So what do I example want to do? Well something like this:
Top 4 clones

```
Username: Elvis-Presley
Clones (Total): 12
Clones (IP): 3
Clones (Machine): 9

Username: Elvis-Presley
Clones (Total): 12
Clones (IP): 3
Clones (Machine): 9

Username: Elvis-Presley
Clones (Total): 12
Clones (IP): 3
Clones (Machine): 9

Username: Elvis-Presley
Clones (Total): 12
Clones (IP): 3
Clones (Machine): 9
```

I've kept it only 4 and the same just to show for example purposes, in the real code it'll order by the total clones they have, showing the most cloney user.

Does anyone know why I am having this issue? I'm not sure why I am, I have took the answer I got off another question but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting top cloners in my Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420730/getting-top-cloners-in-my-database)

Comment: That's the question I got the answer from, it isn't a duplicate, I suggest you read the SO rules and lookup the definition of Duplicate.